# How to get the SSLHostConfig?

Tags: java, tomcat, javabeans, tomcat10, java-17

I am able to get the parent Connector with

```
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        QueryExp qe = Query.match(Query.attr("port"), Query.value("443"));
        ObjectName on = new ObjectName("*:type=Connector,*");
        Set<ObjectName> objectNames = mbs.queryNames(on, qe);
```

and I don't want to read server.xml in case it is out of sync.
How is one to get the SSLHostConfig ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Connector` MBean does not contain information on the TLS configuration. You need to call the method `findSslHostConfigs` on a bean of `type=ThreadPool`. `ThreadPool` is actually a misnomer, since this MBean is exported by each [`ProtocolHandler`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/ProtocolHandler.html).

```java
final MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
final QueryExp qe = Query.eq(Query.attr("port"), Query.value(443));
final ObjectName on = new ObjectName("*:type=ThreadPool,*");
final Set<ObjectName> protocols = mbs.queryNames(on, qe);
for (final ObjectName protocol : protocols) {
    SSLHostConfig[] configs = (SSLHostConfig[]) mbs.invoke(protocol, "findSslHostConfigs", null, null);
    // do something with the SSLHostConfig
}
```

Alternatively the `SSLHostConfig`s are available as MBeans too: they have the property `type=SSLHostConfig`.